# Actionscript 2.0 variable and button issue

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm new here, and I already need help. Typical newb thing, you know?
I'm testing the waters in Actionscript 2.0, since it looked easier to get into than 3.0. I know 3.0 is more powerful and stuff, but babysteps.

Anyway, I'm testing using variables and buttons, but can't get it to work. My code is this:

```
var val = 100;

tstBtn.onRelease = function()
{
    val++;
}
```

Simple enough, right?
On stage I have a dynamic text that tracks the value.

So when I test it and press the button, it works the first time I press it, outputs val=101.

But if I press it again, it goes val=10 and stays there, no matter how many times I press the button again.

Anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try a `trace()` instead of updating that TextField ... it can be an font embedding problem or the TextField size ...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so turns out it's the font and not the script that's messing up. Gee, guess I'm an idiot then. Thanks akmozo! Got it to work.

Tried the trace() and the value is correct. Fixed the font and now it displays correctly.